# Estimate sum of values above a threshold for a population based on sample

Tags: probability, distributions, prediction

I have a sample from a larger data set.  To illustrate my question, here's a sample data set generated with random noise:

```
plot(rnorm(100)) #in R
```

[image]

This sample is 100 points over the entire time range.  Say there are 1000 points over this time range, but I cannot acquire them (only have the sample).

What I want is an estimate of the sum of values above 0.8.

[image]

$\hat{Y} = \sum \text{if} (y_i > 0.8) \text{then } y_i-0.8$

I can calculate this directly for my sample as:

```
Yhat<- 0
Yhat <- ifelse(y>0.8,count + y - 0.8,NA)
sum(Yhat, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 11.67555
```

I want to estimate what $\hat{Y}$ would be for the entire 1000 point range.

It can't be as simple as $z$-score test or a proportion right?

$11.6755/100 = 11.65\%$

$1000 \times 11.65\% = 116.5$ This does not seem valid.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Doing a proportion seems right to get a point estimate. However, you might want a confidence interval. Anyway, beware that in your example 11,65 is not a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach might be to regard the number of exceedances as a Poisson process $N(t)$ with rate $\lambda$, and the sizes of the exceedances as identically distributed random variables $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with mean $\mu$ that are independent of $N(t)$.  You could then use the expected sum as your prediction.  For $t > 0$ this would look like

\begin{align}
\text{E} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i \right ) &= \text{E} \left [ \text{E} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i \mid N(t) \right ) \right ] \\
&= \text{E} \left [ N(t) \text{E} (X_1) \right ] \\
&= \mu \lambda t.
\end{align}

So what you require are estimates for $\mu$ and $\lambda$.  $\mu$ can be estimated using a simple average of exceedances, and to estimate $\lambda$ you would take the total number of exceedances in your sample and divide by $100$.

Comment: On my test data set it works out that $E = \mu \lambda t$ exactly equals the total sum of my exceedances (of the sample set).  Where I set $t$ equal to the length of my test data set (t=100). To estimate it for the population, would I set $t$ equal to the size of the population (t=1000)?

Comment: I would just estimate it over the remaining $900$ time units, so $t = 900$.  Also there's an implicit stationarity assumption here which might be problematic, so it's good to at least be aware of that.

Comment: if my sample rate changes, I gather that $\lambda$=exceedances/observations?  I find that as I increase the size of my sample, relative to total population, the estimate $E$ gets better (not surprisingly)

Answer (score 0):

I see your question as not technically a math or stat or time series issue. For time series prediction in general (your x-axis proves this is a time series analysis) we want to use a large quantity of data to make a prediction for a very short time period after the jump-off. The general rule of thumb is to avoid making far out predictions. You, Lloyd Christmas, are trying to arm wrestle with this age old wisdom by assuming that the 100 observations represent the 1000 population. You just need more data! I even believe a see a pattern in your data related to 60 time periods which means there is a good chance you will go astray with your limited data.

Your dilemma is social influence or political. You need help obtaining more information. As an example without mentioning specific names, I know of a case where the Prime Minister of a nation was able to obtain data that the average person couldn't access. You might need to make new friends to get this one correct. Even if the series cycles every 60 obsevations & you ignore observations 61 thru 100 (& this assumption could be incorrect) the current 60 observations might not be representative of the remaining 15 cycles of 60 observations.

Comment: This is data from a process that continuously creates data.  The time period of  interest is [0,100].  During that time, the process creates 1000 data points, whereas I can only obtain 100 of them.  In this sense I didn't think I was making an inference outside the bounds of my data (since my sample spans the same range as population).

Comment: If the only answer is to get more data... I will need to make friends with the people that set up the data collection system..  Although I was hoping statistics could help me make inferences about my population.

Comment: @Lloyd Christmas Thanks for the update. Maybe I didn't understand the timeline generation. Are your 100 observations equally spaced throughout the 1000 so that your last approx 10 observations might be from 900 and up based on the 1000? Or do you think your 100 observations are from the first 100 of the 1000? Maybe there is some other pattern. Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: The 100 points are equally spaced throughout the 1000, i.e. one sample data point for every 10 points.  Basically the maximum sampling rate I can get is 1/10th of the actual process.

Comment: @Lloyd Christmas I understand  more. Could you grab multiple cycles of "1 sample point every 10" from consecutive 1000 generations so that you could have ,e.g, a 300 count sample after 3 consecutive 1000 generations or 1000 sample points after 10 consecutive 1000 generations? ... just poking in the dark Lloyd because I would want to rule out the possibility that there is a pattern related to 600 population units (or 60 sample units) from your graph. I think I see a pattern. Moreover, do you think the 1000 cut-off makes sense with respect to either yrs, mths, days, hrs, mins, secs? Suspicious?

Comment: I should have said in the OP, that those charts are made from random noise for the purpose of more simply explaining my question rather than trying to use real data.  In this case all the values, including the 1000 point cut off is arbitrary.  I will update the original post because I can now see how that is confusing.

Comment: Ok ... even though the graph doesn't look random